# How to create and share facebook open graph stories in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created a custom object called event and I would like people to perform an action called rsvp. I would like people to be able to share this action eg "Mary has rsvped to Some Event"
I have already created the action and configured the sentences now I just need a way to programatically be able to create events. I have tried using the code:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();


 GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(
      AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
      "me/objects/my_namespace:event",
      params,
      HttpMethod.POST
   );
   GraphResponse response = request.executeAndWait();
```

But I keep getting the error "(#100) The parameter object is required".
My question is What is the step-by-step way from creating open graph stories to sharing them in Android? Also, what does that error mean?

Comment: The error means that you did not supply a parameter named `object`, although it is required. Open Graph Stories always consist of two main ingredients: An Action, and an Object that action is taken upon.

Comment: Can you please post an example of how you would post an open graph story? I would really appreciate it

Comment: The documentation has examples, plus there are “Get Code” buttons in your app dashboard.

Comment: As you can see from the question I have already attempted to use the code from the "Get Code" button but it is returning the error. The documentation is not clear enough.

Comment: There’s different code snippets there for different purposes. You need to use the code for the action, and that should have a second line `params.putString(…)` that actually puts values into that bundle.

Comment: Cool thank you for your help